# PHP mail() function refuses to work if there are more than 7 lines in the $message variable

Tags: php, email

You can see that I tried a couple different ways, but they both do the same thing. If there is anything past the line with the $middle_name variable, the messages fails to send with absolutely no error displayed.

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require_once('get_variables.php');

    // define the receiver of the email
    $to = 'email@email.com';

    // define the subject of the email
    $subject = 'Subject Line';

    // create boundary string. It must be unique
    // so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

    // define the headers we want passed
    $headers = "From: noreply@email.net"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    // read the attachment file contents into a string
    // encode it with MIME base64
    // and split it into smaller chunks
    //$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('')));

    // define the body of the message
    /*ob_start();
    echo '<img src="image.png" width="190" height="100">'
        .'<h3>An application has been received from the online job application form.</h3>'
        .'<hr />'
        .'<strong>Position Applied For:</strong> '.$position_title.'<br />'
        .'<strong>Date Applied: </strong>'.$date.'<br /><br />';

    echo '<strong>First Name: </strong>'.$first_name.'<br />'
        .'<strong>Middle / Maiden: </strong>'.$middle_name.'<br />'
        #.'<strong>Last Name: </strong>'.$last_name.'<br />'
        #.'<strong>Social Security #: </strong>'.$ssn.'<br />'
        .'';

    $message = ob_get_clean();
    */
    $message = '<img src="http://www.beocare.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/BeoCare-Innovation-in-Healthcare.png" width="190" height="100">';
    $message .= '<h3>An application has been received from the online job application form.</h3>';
    $message .= '<hr />';
    $message .= '<strong>Position Applied For:</strong> '.$position_title.'<br />';
    $message .= '<strong>Date Applied: </strong>'.$date.'<br /><br />';
    $message .= '<strong>First Name: </strong>'.$first_name.'<br />';
    $message .= '<strong>Middle / Maiden: </strong>'.$middle_name.'\r\n';
    #$message .= '<strong>Last Name: </strong>'.$last_name.'<br />';
    #$message .= '<strong>Social Security #: </strong>'.$ssn.'<br />';

    //send the email
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

    //if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

Comment: The code working well with my machine. No errors found and mail is received. @Th3Mad

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again: PHP's built in `mail()` function is an absolute nightmare. For the love of sanity, keep far far away from it. Just download [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and use their lovely API to send your emails in PHP. You'll never have to worry about all those things with `mail()` like whether your mail headers are hackable or whether it's actually going to work at all....

Comment: By the way, you've got a `@` in front of your `mail()` call -- that `@` symbol explicitly stops PHP from outputting any error messages. So, uh, if you want to get error messages, maybe try removing the `@`.

Comment: '\r\n' should be used inside **double quotes**  like "\r\n" @Th3

Comment: Maybe you're running into a line length limit, try putting ASCII line breaks in the message after each `<br>`. And take note of @SubinThomas's comment

Comment: I feel like an asshole for asking this but since you put the @ there it might not show you this error... Did you set up smtp?